# How to debug null object field value on ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mode, executenonquery

I've passed an typed object containing multiple field values into an SQL command which calls an *Insert* stored procedure. On debug I can see that each of the fields have a value and none are null.

But when I debug further into the `db.ExecuteNonQuery` call, I get an SQL exception stating that the **Application field is null**. Although it isn't null and has a string value prior to executing this command.

I checked the usual debug steps, the model field type matches the type in the `DbCommand`. Also I checked the `escalation.Application` value prior to executing the query which is populated with a string value as expected.

Question:

Does anyone know why the field value is evaluated as null on `ExecuteNonQuery`?

**Code:**

- DAL class -

  ```
  public bool InsertWebReq(Escalation escalation)
  {
      Database db = null;
      string sqlCommand = "";

      try
      {
          DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
          db = factory.Create("NOTIFICATION");

          sqlCommand = "CREATE_ESCALATION";

          using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand))
          {
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Application", DbType.String, escalation.Application);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "EM", DbType.String, escalation.EM);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "EscalationActions", DbType.String, escalation.EscalationActions);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "ProblemStatement", DbType.String, escalation.ProblemStatement);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "status", DbType.String, escalation.status);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "UpdatedBy", DbType.String, escalation.UpdatedBy);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "UpdatedTime", DbType.DateTime, escalation.UpdatedTime);
              db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Impact", DbType.String, escalation.Impact);

              db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
              return true;
          }
      }
      catch (SqlException ex)
      {
          //Log the SQL specific errors
          for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
          {
              StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

              errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                  "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                  "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                  "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                  "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
          }

          MyLogger.FileLogger.ErrorFormat("{0} - {1}", sqlCommand, ex.Message);
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```
- Model -

  ```
  public partial class Escalation
  {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Application { get; set; }
      public string EM { get; set; }
      public string status { get; set; }
      public string ProblemStatement { get; set; }
      public string Impact { get; set; }
      public string EscalationActions { get; set; }
      public System.DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }
      public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Html element of Application list -

  ```
                          <div class="form-adjacent">
                              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="App">App</label>
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <select id="App" name="Application" onchange="" class="form-control">
                                      <option value="SAP">SAP</option>
                                      <option value="EME">EME</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
  ```

Comment: What does your stored proc look like (create_escalation)?  It seems like you're using AddInParameters and ExecuteNonQuery correctly and you've already stated you're getting a value for Application before actually passing values to the procedure.  Also what's the exact error you're getting about Application being NULL?

Comment: If you are to provide stored procedure code, make sure you show enough to get the right answer, but also make sure to remove any sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, database parameters must start with a @. So if you change your code for this:

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Application", DbType.String, escalation.Application);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@EM", DbType.String, escalation.EM);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@EscalationActions", DbType.String, escalation.EscalationActions);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ProblemStatement", DbType.String, escalation.ProblemStatement);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@status", DbType.String, escalation.status);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@UpdatedBy", DbType.String, escalation.UpdatedBy);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@UpdatedTime", DbType.DateTime, escalation.UpdatedTime);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Impact", DbType.String, escalation.Impact);
```

It should work.

Comment: Only other explanation that I can see is that the stored procedure parameters names don't match those in the data access layer.

Comment: @roryap are you sure it will work without the @? the query analyzer can get confused if there is a column with the same name of the parameter as it is not marked in any way as a parameter...

Comment: @PhilDulac Would you have any idea on this question regarding data reader? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211894/how-to-resolve-an-indexoutofrangeexception-on-bit-value